# Is restarting a VPS used as a web server regularly good?

Tags: vps

I have Debian 7 32bit on my VPS. It's a relatively low-end VPS:

- 50GB HHD, cached to an SSD
- 2.3GHz CPU
- 1Gbps connection
- 128mb RAM

My first thought to this is yes, as a VPS is really a computer with special software. But then I realized that I *wouldn't actually be restarting my server*, I would be restarting a small portion of it.

Is restarting it a good/bad idea? All I have is apache, php and MySQL.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to restart your VPS regularly? Do you experience any problems when it's running for a long time?

Comment: No, but I do very little with it. I was wondering if I should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *need* to restart your virtual server regularly it is probably a bad thing.

Is it *harmful* to restart regularly? Probably not. For physical servers there's a number of mechanical and electro technical reasons why servers are more likely to fail to come back online after a powerdown, but those don't hold for virtuals.

There's always a small risk that even a graceful restart will hang at either the shutdown or boot stage (fsck, new kernel etc.) so most administrators won't schedule unattended restarts.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no good answer to this. You *can* restart your server assuming that you have everything configured correctly it shouldn't cause any issues. Server OSs are designed to stay online for long durations of time and you don't garner too much benefit from it when you consider the loss in availability you'd experience.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend restarting unless you have a good reason to do so. In my case I restart only when I have too many apache process forked and they don't die down and take up too much memory resulting in sluggish response times. Otherwise I don't have a reason to restart it.